# TAP Air Portugal changing flight for free is not possible

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, tap-portugal

I booked a flight from Vienna to Lisbon on the **2nd of July**, with flight date of **7th of September**.
It is a **Classic** ticket, so basically it permits flight changes with a fee: (75€) + difference.

However in July TAP started a new campaign, as the first change is free for everyone: https://www.flytap.com/en-hu/promo/book-with-confidence now they extended this campaign until 31st of August. This was the reason why I bought my ticket, but now things happened and I need to change my flight date from 07th to 17th of September.

Prices are the same, so I think it should be free to change, but their system says I need to pay 75€. I read all their conditions and I am 100%s sure that I should be eligible for a free change.
Also tried to connect customer support in messenger, telephone, even I filled a complaint on their website, but haven't received any answer after 2weeks of waiting.
Obviously I don't want to pay 75€ (from this money I could even buy a new ticket), but I don't know what else options do I have. Cancellation is not possible, I mean I would not get any compensation. (I hope they will cancel it and then I could get a voucher at least.)
What should I do in this situation?
Also, I don't understand why are they advertising things which are not true?

Comment: Is it a fare differential? Can you post a screenshot of the charge, with personal details blanked out?

Comment: In some systems you still have the fee shown but when you proceed further it is then brought to 0. How far in the change process did you go?

Comment: My experience with Covid-19-related terms is that they are not available through existing systems but only by phone. I have seen notices to that effect, explicit warnings not to cancel tickest using the regular procedure and completely incoherent websites (with a ticket marked as both refundable and nonrefundable depending on where you looked on the page). Obviously, it's less than ideal and not being able to reach someone on the phone is especially frustrating in this context but that might account for the discrepancy and not be completely disingenuous.

Comment: I think I went to the final stage of the process, selected new date, and then I saw a screen where I would have had to give my credit card information. Of course I stopped there, price was still 75€ at that point.

Comment: Others also recommended to call them, but after waiting 40minutes for nothing (listening music, instead of speaking with someone) is not so funny especially that some days later I got a huge bill for calling a foreign number.

Comment: Did you book with TAP itself.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Voting to put on hold.